# Is it safe to use windows dependencies in coding if a DLL will be use on multiple platforms?

Tags: c++, dll

First, I am new to C++, so forgive me if the answer is obvious.

Specifically, I am coding in C++, in VS2013, on a windows machine.  What I am wanting to know is, when I am coding a DLL, that may be used on multiple platforms, is it safe for me to use windows specific code.  For example, if I used `__declspec(dllexport)` instead of using a .def file to handle the function exports, would this cause any issues if the end user were to use the DLL on say...a Linux system?

Comment: I don't think you can use a Windows native Dll under OS like Linux. You will have to recompile your Dll under Linux before other program can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use compiler switch within the code body to include appropriate library for Windows or Linux.